# Is there a hand tool for xcode's storyboard (scrolling without scrollbars, PDF style)?

Tags: xcode, mouse, macos

I guess the title says it all. I was looking for a way to e.g. hold down a modifier key and "grab" the storyboard so that I can stop trying to aim for the scrollbars every time I want to scroll freely with a mouse.

I found this key chart http://cocoasamurai.blogspot.se/2011/03/xcode-4-keyboard-shortcuts-now.html but it didn't help.

Comment: This is about a development tool and so would be on topic in StackOverflow it is also on topic here but I suspect there are more Xcode users on SO so try migrating it to there.

Comment: Actually, it's primarily about how multitouch and mouse let a window to scroll. Yes, the tool is for developers, but there is no code here so it's fine to ask here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Smart Scroll](http://www.marcmoini.com/sx_en.html) will help you here. Though it has many features, one of it is grab and scroll, which is exactly what you need.

Comment: That looks interesting, thanks. I'll have to check it out further

Comment: The grab feature had uneven sensitivity on the two axes and didn't feel right, but its vector scrolling is more comfortable anyway. Very good app.

Answer (score 6):

It depends on what type of mouse you're using, but on my magic mouse, I can scroll the storyboard in any direction by dragging one finger over the mouse.

You can also move it around with the command key and arrow keys:

⌘ →   Scroll right

⌘ ←   Scroll left

⌘ ↓   Scroll down

⌘ ↑   Scroll up

Note that you'd have to give the storyboard focus first, by clicking in a blank area.

Comment: Thanks, didn't know that, pretty handy. Unfortunately I have a logitech mouse :)